# How to replace the single slash to double slash in C#?

Tags: c#

Replce single slash to double slash is not working always return the single slash..

```
    string input;
    input = "\r\t";
    string mat1= input.Replace("\\\\","\\\\\\\\");
    string inputt= mat1;
```

if i am run the above code it will return output is \r\t only....

but i need output like this

\r\t

Comment: both "\r" and "\t" are command symbols (carriage return and tabulation) without any slashes, probably you want `input = @"\r\t";`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"\r\t"` is in fact just two characters, carriage return and tab. This is because [the `\` escape character is used to specify special characters](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/csharpfaq/2004/03/12/what-character-escape-sequences-are-available/).

If you want to have a string that is actually `"\r\t"` you need to escape the `\` characters by using `\\`.

So your string should be:

```
input = "\\r\\t";
```

Or

```
input = @"\r\t";
```

And then to replace the backslashes with double backslashes:

```
string mat1= input.Replace("\\","\\\\");
```

Or

```
string mat1= input.Replace(@"\", @"\\");
```

Comment: when am pass the input as another input string  like "Input=text;" and text="\t\r".. its not working...it will take single slash..

Comment: @user6479492 Can you post a compilable example? (You might need to create a new question for it)

Answer (score 0):

`input = "\r\t";`

is a so called escaped string. \ means escape sequence. if you need \r\t you need to write

`input = "\\r\\t";`

Answer (score 0):

This is 2 already escaped characters, not 4.

```
input="\r\t";
```

Answer (score 0):

`\r` and `\t` are special literals. [Check this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691087(v=vs.71).aspx):

> `\r` - Carriage return
>
> `\t` - Horizontal tab

What you wanted, I gess, is to change this special literal like this:

```
string input;
input = "\r\t";
input = input.Replace("\r", "\\r");
input = input.Replace("\t", "\\t");
Console.WriteLine(input);
```